Inverse-Wishart Posterior for Gibbs Sampling
I've a question regarding Gibb's sampling where I'm stuck at a particular point. 
Let B has a prior Inverse-Wishart Distribution IW($aI_3$,b). Now if I've data such that:
\begin{equation}
\mu \sim MVN_{3n}(M,(A \otimes B))
\end{equation}
B is a $3 \times 3$ matrix, A is $n \times n$ and $\mu, M$ are $3n \times 3n$.
where MVN stands for multivariate normal distribution. I want to find the posterior of B.
I'm able to form the likelihood but unable to separate it (like how to evaluate this):
\begin{equation}
(\mu-M)^T(A^{-1} \otimes B^{-1})(\mu-M)=tr(B^{-1}S)
\end{equation}
How to find S?
